# Yacc - productions for matching functions

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, yacc

I am writing a compiler with Yacc and having trouble figuring out how to write productions  to match a function. In my language, functions are defined like this:

```
function foo(a, b, c);
```

I created lex patterns to match the word function to FUNC, and any C style name to NAME.

Ideally, I would want something like this:

```
FUNC NAME OBRACKET NAME (COMMA NAME)* CBRACKET
```

Which would allow some unknown number of pairs of COMMA NAME in between NAME and CBRACKET.

Additionally, how would I know how many it found?

Comment: Can we use the correct terminology please. 'Production', not 'pattern'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little experimentation, I found this to work quite well:

```
int argCount;
int args[128];

arglist: nonemptyarglist
       |
        ;

nonemptyarglist: nonemptyarglist COMMA singleArgList
               | singleArgList
        {

        };

singleArgList:
            REGISTER
        {
            args[argCount++] = $1;
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this:

```
funcdecl: FUNC NAME OBRACKET arglist CBRACKET SEMI
;

arglist: nonemptyarglist
       |
;

nonemptyarglist: nonemptyarglist COMMA NAME
               | NAME
;
```

I'd suggest using the grammar to build a syntax tree for your language and then doing whatever you need to the syntax tree after parsing has finished.  Bison and yacc have features that make this rather simple; look up `%union` and `%type` in the info page.

Comment: How would I extract the value of `NAME` in `nonemptyarglist`?

$3 or $1?